# Logs of Ubuntu going into Sleep and waking up?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I need to know about the times the Ubuntu (14/16) went to sleep or woke up. are these logs kept somewhere? thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The favorite place for me (but not the only place) is accessed using:

```
gedit /var/log/syslog
```

To view older log records look at:

```
gedit /var/log/syslog.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this file only keeps the logs of  a few of previous hours and not longe and it doesn't keep the logs I needed

Comment: I updated the answer to look at older records. I'd older than that use '.2', '.3', etc.

Answer (score 28):

In case your Ubuntu is using systemd, you can use:

```
journalctl | grep systemd-sleep
```

You should get something like:

```
Jul 31 16:02:51 johndoe systemd-sleep[5958]: Suspending system...
Aug 01 15:34:03 johndoe systemd-sleep[25509]: Suspending system...
Aug 02 09:01:40 johndoe systemd-sleep[25509]: System resumed.
Aug 02 16:59:16 johndoe systemd-sleep[23496]: Suspending system...
Aug 06 08:46:04 johndoe systemd-sleep[23496]: System resumed.
Aug 06 17:05:08 johndoe systemd-sleep[6071]: Suspending system...
Aug 07 08:41:33 johndoe systemd-sleep[6071]: System resumed.
Aug 07 16:48:01 johndoe systemd-sleep[14495]: Suspending system...
Aug 08 09:06:48 johndoe systemd-sleep[14495]: System resumed.
Aug 08 16:38:55 johndoe systemd-sleep[14729]: Suspending system...
Aug 09 07:53:48 johndoe systemd-sleep[14729]: System resumed.
```

Comment: Yes, I see this however it does not help to diagnose why it freezes after 10-20 sec after the resume: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247968/ubuntu-freezes-after-resume-from-suspend-hibernate-in-10-15-sec