# System refuses to suspend

Tags: server, lubuntu, suspend, power-management, amd-processor

Lubuntu 18.04 (lxde) here, upon AMD Epyc 7282. Kernel 4.15.
The system is stable and works flawlessly, but id does refuse to suspend.

If I try to suspend it, the screen blanks, but the system does not power off.

At this point, if I hit a key or move the mouse, nothing happens. If I hit the power button, the system "wakes up", presenting the login screen, and then all the applications as I left them.

Hibernation is absent alltogether.

Note that Epyc Rome is not affected by the notorious RDRAND bug which affects Ryzen 3000 and causes problems with suspend to ram.

EDIT: I used the system for days with high load, and can confirm rock stability, but if I leave it blanking the monitor, there is no way to wake it up.. One has to connect via ssh and reset the system.

EDIT(**II**): Example output for `journalctl -u systemd-suspend.service`:

```
gen 25 04:33:52 epyc systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
gen 25 04:33:52 epyc systemd-sleep[1743]: Suspending system...
gen 25 04:34:36 epyc systemd-sleep[1743]: System resumed.
gen 25 04:34:36 epyc systemd-sleep[1743]: /dev/sda:
gen 25 04:34:36 epyc systemd-sleep[1743]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
gen 25 04:34:36 epyc systemd-sleep[1743]:  APM_level        = 254
```

**EDIT** (**III**): I actually managed to hibernate the system using `uswsusp`, by specifying explicitly the resume device, that is, the swap partition:

```
sudo s2disk -r /dev/sda1
```

In such condition the system does shut down visualizing `SNAPSHOTTING THE SYSTEM...`

If I power on, the system does boot saying `RESUMING FROM HIBERNATION...` but then, it just displays the desktop, with no trace of any application left open. I will investigate the logs and report back.

Comment: If you suspend via command `systemctl suspend`  does it suspend correctly?

Comment: No, it does not. Actually I am interested mainly in this way of suspending it, since I will use the system primarily by ssh. Thanks.

Comment: For hibernating the system you would need a swap partition as far as I know. I once tried it with just creating a swap file but that seemed a little buggy to me. What does `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend` tell you?

Comment: Does masking suspend and hibernation with `sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target` give you any errors? And does unmasking it with `sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target` give you some hints to solve your issues?

Comment: look through the log file `/var/log/syslog`.  Or `journalctl --since 9:00 --until "1 minute ago"` --since time system went to sleep    --until time system woke up or tried to anyway.

Comment: Also `journalctl -u systemd-suspend.service`

Comment: Have you noticed this answer? https://askubuntu.com/a/1152359/925971 In my case starkus comment helped. I used `sudo systemctl unmask...` command. So it could be an answer I will upvote.

Comment: @starkus: `gsettings [...]` gives me `true`. Masking just creates a symlink `Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sleep.target → /dev/null.`, while unmasking says `Removed /etc/systemd/system/sleep.target.`. Does this say anything to you?

Comment: @da_kingpin, since its too long to put it in the comments, I edited my question.

Comment: @Gryu, thanks, but it's not that the system do awake immediately. It's more that it just refuses to suspend, apart from blanking the screen. Or rather I'm not noticing something?

Comment: You can see if more log information is available in syalog:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/841197/logs-of-ubuntu-going-into-sleep-and-waking-up:

Comment: @da_kingpin I have all SSDs, and they didn't hinder my sleep or hibernation in my previous Xeon system.

Comment: @MadHatter ...the masking and unmasking messages look way regular to me. I would give `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false` a try to disable the lock screen after suspend. You can undo that with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true`.

Comment: In case this helps and you need the lock screen you could use a systemd resume script in `/etc/systemd/system/resume@.service`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, the syslog is a real mess.. Can you tell me what should I search for, generally speaking? Thanks

Comment: Look at your watch when you suspend. Then when you resume you should see that time when you press the `end` key in gedit

Comment: I'll do it and report back. Meanwhile, please look at my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Some ACPI BIOS have been know to be buggy in linux and this may not work with all systems. I do believe hibernation is disabled by default with ubuntu flavors. Check and make sure the file `/etc/default/grub` contains the `resume` parameter in the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` near the beginning of the file. To quickly check, from a terminal type:

```
head -n 15 /etc/default/grub
```

The line should read something like this example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=26623446-028a-415d-e685-8adc53740282"
```

If your resume value instead contains `resume=/dev/sda1`, I would suggest changing that to a UUID number. The device identifier "/dev/sda1" is not always persistent and could possibly change when a new drive is introduced to the system. The UUID will remain unique. To find the UUID# of your swap partition:

```
lsblk -o +uuid | grep -i swap
```

As a good habit, make a backup copy of the original file before changing.

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/~grub.bak.`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`
```

If you have made any changes to the `/etc/default/grub` file, you will need to  update the grub configuration:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Read the output and confirm that initramfs resume hook is pointing to the correct partition.
Then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then try to hibernate system:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

If system immediately resumes then login and read `dmesg` to see any recent [PM] errors and look over the logs again to find what may be the issue.

Comment: That's an interesting answer, although I won't be able to check it before the bounty expires. I'll try and reissue the bounty tomorrow.