# Ubuntu freezes after resume from suspend/hibernate in 10-15 sec

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, suspend, dell

Bought new laptop - [Dell Latitude-5501](https://www.dell.com/ru/business/p/latitude-15-5501-laptop/pd) with Ubuntu 18.04.4. Works fine, however the only problem exists: after I close laptop cover or after some time of inactivity Ubuntu suspends or hibernate (do not know). After I resume it, it starts to work but in 10-15 sec Ubuntu freezes and I forced to power-off.

Tried many things mentioned here:

- blacklist nouveau
- install older kernel - 4.14.41
- update to newer - 4.18 or latest 5.3 kernel
- switch to proprietary nvidia driver (was installed by default)
- install `lightdm` instead of `gdm3`
- dell software had run some recent firmware upgrade
- etc

Nothing work - it still freezes and it is impossible to work. The only suggestion I did not tried yet: install kubuntu and then original nvidia driver from manufacturer site. Do not know however if it affects warranty? ;) Any ideas how to solve, how to diagnose? Thanks!

System, hardware and security logs during suspend/resume attached (original 4.15 kernel):

- [System.log](https://pastebin.com/0Ttnu7T9)
- [Security.log](https://pastebin.com/Wme1y1wM)
- [Hardware.log](https://pastebin.com/ujUS5Ce4)

Logs for 4.18 kernel are slightly different:

- [System_4.18.log](https://pastebin.com/WVNXiFdA)
- [Hardware_4.18.log](https://pastebin.com/RphtPj0w)
- [Software_4.18.log](https://pastebin.com/CwypQ4VF)
- [Security_4.18.log](https://pastebin.com/VV2ck2un)

Comment: When the OS freezes, try pressing ALT+SysRq+F.

Comment: Use any software such as Gnome Logs to view the logs from that time when the OS freezes.

Comment: @Puspam where is SysRq key on the [notebook keyboard](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln317544/latitude-5501-keyboard-function-guide?lang=en)?!  How to invoke it? However I was able to run system monitor and see no application which eats memory for this.

Comment: @Puspam Thanks for the Gnome Logs, where to put the output? What section You interested in? Put all together or separate sections by apps, system, hardware?I see some stacktrace there but not sure what module it causes.

Comment: SysRq key is the same as the `Print Screen` key. For the logs-- I think that's something to do with the system. So, look in the `System` section. Post it with your question. Look for the logs from the time when the OS wakes up from suspend till it freezes.

Comment: @Puspam added logs for original 4.15 and 4.18 kernels. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04 LTS. On install uncheck

- [ ] «Install this third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware, Flash, MP3 and other media»

After OS install, install nvidia drivers manually - run in Konsole:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440 nvidia-settings
```

Above will install `nvidia-settings` correctly.

Then reboot in KDE. After above Suspend mode work ok on timeout and cover close.